# console error for jquery function?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am looking at my jquery function on my page and for some reason im getting this error, "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function". Here is my jquery I do not know what to do for this error?

JQUERY:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('body').on('click', '.like', function(){
  if($(this).attr('title')=='like'){
   $.post('/like.php',{imid:$(this).attr('id'),action:'like'});
    $(this).removeClass('like').addClass('unlike').attr('title', 'unlike');
  }
})
    .on('click', '.unlike', function(){
   if($(this).attr('title')=='unlike'){
    $.post('/like.php',{imid:$(this).attr('id'),action:'unlike'});
   $(this).removeClass('unlike').addClass('like').attr('title', 'like');
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: If you are using chrome, you should have a link in front of your error linking the line with your error

Comment: which version of JQuery are you using?

Comment: $('body').on('click', '.like', function(){
i believe it is this line that is is referring to ?

Comment: Well I just tested here : http://jsfiddle.net/P6jPu/ there seems to be no problems with your code ...

Comment: could there be an error because of some other javascript or jquery on the page above this script ?